# Maximal Consecutive Integer Sequence

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

I'm doing up solutions to some junior Olympiad problems and am somewhat stumped by one of the questions:

> Can you find a sequence of 14 consecutive positive integers such that each is divisible by an element of $ \{ 2,3,5,7,11 \} $?

Obviously you could generalise this problem as

> What is the maximal number $N$ of consecutive positive integers such that each is divisible by one of the first $n$ primes?

in which case our original problem reduces to the case $n=5$.

I've tried looking at the pattern of numbers modulo the product of the first $n$-primes but haven't really gotten anywhere substantial. I suspect there's a very simple solution. Any input on the specific and/or generalised problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For the first, I'd let $N=2\times 3\times 5\times 7 \times 11$ and look at $\{N+2,N+3,\cdots, N+16\}$.

Comment: @lulu What would be  the factors of $N+13$?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг  Forgot $13$!  Absolutely correct, my example fails.

Comment: @lulu That is why I feel this question is odd because somewhere you need fourteen consecutive numbers, where the first of these isn't a multiple of all of $2,3,5,7,11$, so that $N+13$ goes through. Then, we may be able to answer the question. However, it does beg the question, that in an olympiad without access to a computer, how would one come up with such numbers.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг  Check my post below, lest I have made another blunder.

Comment: This appears to be studied under the name [Jacobsthal function](https://oeis.org/wiki/Jacobsthal_function). If I am reading this link correctly, it appears that $14$ is impossible for the first problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the sequence $n, n+1, n+2, \dots, n+13$. Seven of these numbers are even, and the other seven form the sequence $m, m+2, m+4, m+6, m+8, m+10, m+12$, where $m$ is either $n$ or $n+1,$ whichever is odd.

We can show that the seven integers $m, m+2, m+4, m+6, m+8, m+10$, and $m+12$ can’t all be divisible be one of the four odd primes $3$, $5$, $7$, and $11$.

How many of these seven integers can each of the four odd primes divide?

The seven integers differ by even numbers no larger than $12$, so $11$ can only divide **one** of them.

Similarly, no two of them differ by $7$ or a larger multiple of $7$, so only **one** can be divisible by $7$.

No two of them differ by $5$, but two pairs have difference $10$, so either both $m$ and $m+10$ are divisible by $5$, or both $m+2$ and $m+12$ are divisible by $5$, or only one of the seven is divisible by $5$. So $5$ can divide at most **two** of the seven numbers.

And finally, the only subsets of the seven that could be multiples of $3$ are $\{m,m+6,m+12\}$, $\{m+2, m+8\}$, and $\{m+4,m+10\}$. The prime $3$ could (and does) divide the members of exactly one of those subsets, so $3$ divides at most **three** of the seven.

Now we know that $11$ and $7$ divide at most one each of the seven numbers, $5$ divides at most two, and $3$ divides at most three. In order for this to take care of all seven of the numbers, the primes $11$, $7$, $5$, and $3$ must divide one, one, two, and three of the numbers, respectively, and these multiples (one of $11$, one of $7$, two of $5$, and three of $3$) must be distinct.

However, this is impossible, because the only way $3$ can divide three of the seven is if it divides both $m$ and $m+12$, and for $5$ to divide two of the seven, one of the two must be $m$ or $m+12$.

I can’t think of a way to generalize easily, but this approach, though tedious, should be applicable to larger collections of primes.